# Uploading TVOS app with the same BundleID of the iOS app error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, provisioning-profile, tvos

I've developed a `TVOS` app as an extension for my existing `iOS` app.

I've added the `TVOS` app to the same Xcode project of the iOS app, using a different Target, and gave it the same BundleID as the iOS app.

For some reason, when I try to archive the `TVOS` app, I get these errors:

[image: Error Image]

It is worth to mention that the `iOS` app still works fine, and I can archive it without a problem.

Does anyone knows why is it happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Provisioning profiles can not be shared between iOS and tvOS.

You'll need to create new provisioning profiles for your tvOS application using the same bundle identifier as your iOS application in the [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/).

[image: tvos-provisioning-profiles]